# OnClick events are refreshing page in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, events, onclick

I am using Firestore as my database to gather data and present it through a repeater to create cards on my Kesitler.aspx page using C#. My main issue is that when I click on an asp:Button element, it refreshes the page, which I don't want to happen. While it ,seem basic, I haven't found a straightforward solution yet. I prefer not to use the JavaScript onClick functionality because the click should affect the database operation, I want to set data after the click event without initializing the database in the JavaScript script. Is there a solution to this problem?

The code in Kesitler.aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

and the code in Kesitler.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Resss");
}
```

I have tried to use Response.Redirect(Kesitler.aspx) and that didn't worked for me.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done this but try adding something like `onclientclick="return 0;"` to the server side `Button` declaration

Comment: If you want just to refresh a part of the page with some data from database you have  to use some javascript. (the "why" is  too long for a comment). Maybe have a look at [Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-8.0) or other [client side technologies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-client-side-web-technologies)

Comment: `My main issue is that when I click on an asp:Button element, it refreshes the page, which I don't want to happen. ` In webform app, to achieve your requirement, there are only two possible approaches: 1) using updatepanel control to prevent full page refreshing 2) using ajax to post data on js client

Answer (score 0):

If you have a button in your webform, and you click on it, then the web page is posted back to the server. The reason for this is thus then code behind can use, see, and modify controls on the web page with server-side code. If you don't post-back, then the web page is still sitting on the user’s desktop, and thus you would not be able to change or modify controls on that page.

So, there are several approaches here.

Call a web method, and pass values from the few controls on the page. And if the results need to be displayed on the page, then the web method will have to return such values, and your client-side JavaScript will then update the controls on the page.

Another possible is to adopt what we call a "partial" page post back. In most cases, this means the client-side variables will remain intact, and you don't suffer a full page post-back.

Hence, you can use what is called an update panel. This will in effect "ajax" part of your page automatic for you, and no JavaScript need be written for this to work.

So, include the button, and any other control the code behind needs to update inside of the update panel.

So, the design patter looks like this:

First, drag from the toolbox a script manager - it is to be placed right have the "form" tag in your markup.

Then drag in an update panel.

So, you have then this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Now, later on in your markup, then you can do this:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <h3>Place all markup and controls and buttons</h3>
                <h3>Inside of this area to ajax</h3>

                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"
                    OnClick="Button1_Click1"
                    />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So, inside of the above update panel, place all your markup inside of the content template.

Now, when you click on that button, ONLY that part of the page will be posted back to the server. (You not even see the browser spinner, and from all points of view, it will seem like the page was NOT posted back.

Do keep in mind that a page life cycle does trigger, and like all pages, the page load event will trigger first (like always), and then the button code stub will run.

So, try the above idea. It should preserve the value(s) of the existing client-side JavaScript values. So, place only the content and controls you want to "ajax" on that page. You thus can have a standard button click and code behind run, but your client-side JavaScript values will remain intact, and not be re-set.